# arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()

Tags: raspberry-pi

Getting the following cross compiling for RPi on Debian Wheezy x64 using the gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian toolchain within Eclipse Kepler. Compilation works fine using native Debian x64 GCC and native GCC compiler on the RPi. Any ideas?

> out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 2 exit status
>
> make: *** [cwebsocket] Error 1

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tried searching Google. Most hits were related to yy_create_buffer PHP crashes. Not much out there, hence my first post to SO. Perhaps the RPI dev list would be a better place?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with:

LINK_FLAGS += --sysroot=/{path to embedded's root dir} -L/{path to embedded's root dir}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf

(note that although I've set the "chroot" system root, I am specifying the include directory from the real root)

Error disappeared with:

LINK_FLAGS += --sysroot=/{path to embedded's root dir} -L/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf