# How does using -L affect the linker?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, linker, ld

I'm rather new on Linux, so maybe this is a simple question.

The question is: *How does adding a `-L/path` affect the linker when there are no libraries attached?*

#### my issue:

I'm trying to set up a cross-compilation toolchain featuring two pieces of third-party libraries¹.

I'm using the linaro `arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian` chain (target is a raspberry pi) and it seems to work okay.

One of my modules does not require any linked libraries, and it compiles fine and runs on the target.

The one that tries linking my libraries compiles, but after thinking for a bit, it comes smashing down on linking with the message

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc foo1.o foo2.o foo3.o ... foo12.o foo13.o -L/path/path/path/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/lib -lbar1 -lbar2 -lbar3 -o foo
out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()
collect2: error: ld returned 2 exit status
```

A search of history on this question only rustles up [arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087280/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-out-of-dynamic-memory-in-yy-create-buffer) which has no replies, so I'm assuming I'm on my own here. I couldn't find anything on Linaro either.

Linaro comes with two ld's, `.brf` and `.gold,` the behaviour seems similar between them. My gcc is linaro-1.13.1-4.8-2014.01.

As mentioned I have this other module, which compiles fine with

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc foo.o -o foo
```

But it shows the same error as above if I compile it with

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc foo.o -L/path/path/path/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/lib -o foo
```

So I get the impression it's all from that `-L` option.

Further data points: When I ran `arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld` with `crt*.o` and the rest of the stuff above, I ran out of swap space. So I increased the swap space from 500M to 2G. Then it told me it ran out of fd's. So I increased the fd's from 1024 to 65000. Then it told me LD runs out of memory. Not sure how I should address that. Not even sure that I should.

Oh, and this is on a Ubuntu Virtualbox.

So, finally, the question: What does this `-L` do? Why does the linker behave differently with the `-L` on? My linker is located in `/path/path/path/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin`. Why should it even care when I'm not linking any libraries?

---

¹ (Yay! Fun for the whole family)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your direct question, unless you produce a static binary (by default linker will produce a dynamic one), there are default libraries to link with (libc, for one). Specifying `-L` does tell the linker to first look in the directories specified. It's not `gcc` thank links, but `ld`, `gcc` simply calls `ld`, passing some extra parameters, including default libraries to link with.

To try to help you with your problem:

Your `ld` seems to choke hard on some of the libraries found in `/path/path/path/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/lib`, or on something that is referenced from there.

Try adding `-v` and `-Wl,-v` flags to gcc when linking, to get more information about what the linker and compiler are doing. Make sure you don't have any `LD_*` environment variables set. Make sure the linker picked up and the library directory you are using are from the same tool chain.

Problems like that are usually caused by wrong configuration, or wrong files being picked up at the wrong time. Further debugging will require debugging the linker using `strace` or `gdb`.

If you can reproduce this problem with a specific version of the toolchain, and can post the code that it chokes on, you can post the exact references, and somebody may be able to take a look at those.

Comment: Hey, Pawel. Thanks for helping out. I tried gdb, and it took me out into no-man's land, so that wasn't particularly useful. strace showed me that it would continually be calling 3 libraries in order that would each attempt to claim some memory. So I recompiled those and it seemed to run.